# stored procedure to add movie into queue

Tags: database, oracle

I have the following code to add a title to a customer's movie list or queue. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong/not doing to make this work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_movie_queue
(MEMBERID_arg IN NUMBER, 
DVDTITLE_arg IN VARCHAR2, 
DATEADDEDINQUEUE_arg IN DATE,
QUEUEPOSITION_arg IN INTEGER)

IS
next_movie INTEGER;
current_month INTEGER;


BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO current_month FROM RENTAL
WHERE MEMBERID = MEMBERID_arg AND RENTALRETURNEDDATE IS NULL;

SELECT DVDID INTO next_movie FROM RENTALQUEUE
WHERE RENTALQUEUE.MEMBERID = MEMBERID_arg
AND DATEADDEDINQUEUE_arg = (SELECT MIN(DATEADDEDINQUEUE) FROM RENTALQUEUE
WHERE MEMBERID = MEMBERID_arg);

INSERT INTO RENTALQUEUE(MEMBERID,DVDID,DATEADDEDINQUEUE,QUEUEPOSITION)
VALUES(MEMBERID_arg,next_movie,DATEADDEDINQUEUE_arg,QUEUEPOSITION_arg);

END;
```

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem?  You have syntax errors (missing semicolon) ;

Comment: well the last line of 'VALUES' i get error: Error(21,57): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "QUEUEPOSITION": invalid identifier

Comment: That error indicates that `QUEUEPOSITION` is not a column in the `RENTALQUEUE` table.  Perhaps there is a spelling error?